# Pivot table Sort month for different years

Tags: excel, sorting, date, pivot-table

Hi I am pivoting data grouped by months. The months are spanned across 2 years with the start date being in july 2018 going back to august 2017. However when i try to sort the data, it always start with Jan 2018 first and goes alphabetically. How can i make it do chronologically. Also is there a way to change the date to say m/yy? I keepy trying field settings then number format and its not working

```
Date
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec
<8/1/2017
```

Comment: Select your data > right click > format cells > format by Date > select mm/yyyy

Comment: @cameron cole that doesnt work, when i select the cells in the pivot format cells isnt an option

Comment: It's probably because your sorting A-Z you need to try a custom sort.

Comment: Why not group on years and months? That would put the months in chronological order.

Comment: @MarcoVos can you post that as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @CameronCole I dont think you can do custom sorts with pivots like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option could be to group years as well. Right-click a cell with one of the months > group > select Years and months. This will put the months in chronological order.